# Need equivalent of JSP tag in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf. In jsp world I could change the theme of my Springboot Web [Application](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootAjaxFormBSModal/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp) using the following tags in "head" of a jsp:

```
<spring:theme code="stylesheet" var="themeName" />
<link href='<spring:url value="css/${themeName}"/>' rel="stylesheet" />
```

What should I write "as the exact equivalent of above" if I am going to use "Thymeleaf template" instead of jsp? I am using (and must use) spring boot (with web and data). Can someone please point me a way out?

**Update**

Adding more information.

I have my [config](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootAjaxFormBSModal/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springboot/is/rocking/config/MvcWebConfig.java) and beans as per following:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/css**", "/resources/static/**", "/static/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
}

@Bean
public ThemeSource themeSource() {
    ResourceBundleThemeSource themeSource = new ResourceBundleThemeSource();
    themeSource.setBasenamePrefix("theme/");
    return themeSource;
}

@Bean
public ThemeResolver themeResolver() {
    CookieThemeResolver resolver = new CookieThemeResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultThemeName("cosmo");
    return resolver;
}
```

And also I have bunch of (e.g. Cosmo.BootStrap.min.css) under themes folder. When I select the theme name from [JSP](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootAjaxFormBSModal/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp), the theme of my entire webapp gets changed.

In short, using Thymeleaf, in my "header.html fragment", I am trying to acheive something similar to this (**${somename}**) -

```
<link href="css/${somename}.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For now I am clueless. Please give some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always build dynamic URLs in Thymeleaf like:

```
<head th:with="themeName=${'stylesheet'}">
  <link th:href="@{|/css/${themeName}|}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

Now `themeName` can either be populated from the controller in the `Model` or `ModelMap` class, or computed in the template HTML.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and will update you the outcome.