# Changing .css files links via .properties files

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to achieve those theme change solutions: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-themes or http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2017/04/spring-mvc-themeresolver.html but with **Thymeleaf** instead of the `.jsp`.
But I can't see any style change on my application.

I think the problem is `href/th:href` attribute.
I have tried many solutions but can't change `href="<spring:theme code='styleSheet'/>"` from `.jsp` in a valid Thymeleaf expression.
And this bellow is the only solution that works.

**th:href="${@environment.getProperty('stylesheet')}"**
But there are still no styles in HTML, and when I run inspect element there are no .css files included.

Here is the code example:

```
@Configuration
public class ThemeConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public ThemeResolver themeResolver() {
        CookieThemeResolver themeResolver = new CookieThemeResolver();
        themeResolver.setDefaultThemeName("light");
        return themeResolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public ThemeChangeInterceptor themeChangeInterceptor() {
        ThemeChangeInterceptor interceptor = new ThemeChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("theme");
        return interceptor;
    }
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(themeChangeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Html

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="${@environment.getProperty('stylesheet')}">
...
</head>
<body>
...
    <div class="dropdown-container ms-4">
                        <a th:href="@{?theme=dark}">[[#{dashboard.theme-dark}]]</a>
                        <a th:href="@{?theme=light}">[[#{dashboard.theme-light}]]</a>
                        <a th:href="@{?theme=blue}">[[#{dashboard.theme-blue}]]</a>
                    </div>
...</body>
```

dark.properties (I have also tried: stylesheet=dark.css, stylesheet=/themes/dark.css, etc..)

```
stylesheet=/css/themes/dark.css
background=black
```

dark.css

```
footer{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[image: File structure - css]
[image: File structure - .properties files]

Comment: Check the code for the Theme tag and see what it does. You cannot get the properties through the `environment` variable you need the `themeSource` for that (which you seem to be missing). You might want to write a dialect which as a replacement for the theme tag in JSP. Also take into account that as of Spring 6 the Theme support has been deprecated and will probably be removed in 6.1 or 6.2.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have also tried with ThemeSource and ResourceBundleThemeSource but still the same results. Also, I tried to switch tag in JSP as it is explained in this solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079682/need-equivalent-of-jsp-tag-in-thymeleaf)
but that neither works. 
Only `@environment.getProperty()` doesn't show this error: `"Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8888/user/code?stylesheet' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."` but still has not loaded CSS as it should.

Comment: @M.Deinum When I run the inspect element, sources tab it shows me that my link looks like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="">`
So the path is empty. It is not loaded from the .properties file

Comment: As stated **you cannot use the `environment` to get the properties**. You **must use the `ThemeSource`**. Which means you are missing parts in your configuration (the `ThemeSource`) and you should use that to get the confguration for the `Theme`. Your linked "solution" isn't a solution it is a suggestion to expose the theme-name and do stuff in Thymeleaf. So again, use the `ThemeSource` and you probably want to write a Thymeleaf Dialect to mimic the `ThemeTag` behavior from JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Theme support is deprecated in Spring 6 I will use JavaScript as an easy workaround.